# How do I change the icon that appears on the Android Wear notification card for notifications generated by Tasker with AutoNotification?

Tags: android, wear-os, tasker

I'm using Tasker, with AutoNotification, to send notifications to a connected Android Wear device. I know how to change the icon for the notifications in the notification bar for the Android phone itself, but the icon that appears on the notification card for Android Wear is always the AutoNotification icon. This is true even after I've converted the Tasker task into an app of its own, with its own icon.

How can I change that icon to one of my own devising?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using AutoWear?
Id recommend that over AutoNotification as it is designed for wear devices, thus delivers far more possibilities... ;)